# Testing js\ts\tsx have only one export (the default one )

Tags: javascript, testing, babeljs

Im using a package that requires the files that are using it would only have one export (the export default one ).

I want to verify at build ( transpilation ) time and not at run time since its breaking my app.
How can I do that?